# How to sum the values in if condition?

Tags: perl

My output has the many values. But sum the particular values.
My answer from the script like this

```
# $ans 
3.801
5.381
16.26
3.801
18.3
3.80
5.151
5.636
6.732
.
.
.

my $sum;
if($ans <= 8)
{ 
     $sum += $ans;
     print "$ans\n\n\n";

}
print "Total value below (8) : $sum";
```

How to sum the answer below 8 outside of the if condition? How can i do it?

Answer (score 6):

Another way that doesn't need a module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sum;
$_ < 8 and $sum += $_ while <DATA>;

print "Total value below (8): $sum\n";

__DATA__
3.801
5.381
16.26
3.801
18.3
3.80
5.151
5.636
6.732
```

**output**

```
Total value below (8): 34.302
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use grep to filter out numbers you don't want from your list, and then use [`List::Util qw(sum)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(sum);

my $sum = sum grep {$_ < 8} <DATA>;

print $sum;

__DATA__
3.801
5.381
16.26
3.801
18.3
3.80
5.151
5.636
6.732
```

Outputs:

```
34.302
```